# Using T4 with .NET Core 2.0 and referencing a package from a template

Tags: .net-core, t4

I tried using T4 in a .NET Core 2.0 app project but it seems that T4 doesn't recognize included namespaces. For example, after installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package and having the following piece of code:

```
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" #>

<#+ 

public class ConfigurationHelper
{

    public string ReadConfig(){
        
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("Configuration\\CodeGenerationConfig.json");

            IConfigurationRoot  Configuration = builder.Build();
            
            return Configuration["ConnectionString:Server"];
        }
}

#>
```

I got the error:

> The type or namespace name 'IConfigurationRoot' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Even I tried using assembly directive:

> <#@  assembly name="C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\store\x64\netcoreapp2.0\microsoft.extensions.configuration\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll"
>
> ## >

But the following error occurred:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'file:///C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\store\x64\netcoreapp2.0\microsoft.extensions.configuration\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll'
> or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be
> verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay
> signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

So the question is how can I reference a .NET Core package from within a T4 template?

P.S: I tried [Scripty](https://github.com/daveaglick/Scripty), but it doesn't support .NET Core yet.

Comment: I guess T4 hasn't adapted .net core yet.

Comment: do you find any solution on this

Answer (score 1):

Update:

The Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin Studio now supports to process *.tt files in desing time

but https://github.com/ZeekoZhu/TextTemplatingCore may still be useful if you want to process T4 templates in a dotnet core(netstandard2.0) 
project outside IDE (eg. in Linux or macOS with Visual Studio Code)